# Gunicorn - starting server issue?

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

I am having this issue to start my gunicorn server, but it seems like it's failing to start the server after I did reload daemon and enable my updated gunicorn system. I checked two or three times to make sure all's correct, so alls correct. After I started it, the first error message stating `Job for gunicorn-superlists-staging.bdienterprises.com.service failed because of unavailable resources or another system error.` Pls see the errors after I checked its systemctl status gunicorn-mydomain below:

```
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn-superlists-staging.bdienterprises.com.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabl
   Active: failed (Result: resources) since Sat 2020-05-09 15:37:12 UTC; 9min ago

May 09 15:37:12 avidfisherman systemd[1]: gunicorn-superlists-staging.bdienterprises.com.service: Service hold-off time over
May 09 15:37:12 avidfisherman systemd[1]: gunicorn-superlists-staging.bdienterprises.com.service: Scheduled restart job, res
May 09 15:37:12 avidfisherman systemd[1]: Stopped Gunicorn server for superlists-staging.bdienterprises.com.
May 09 15:37:12 avidfisherman systemd[1]: gunicorn-superlists-staging.bdienterprises.com.service: Start request repeated too
May 09 15:37:12 avidfisherman systemd[1]: gunicorn-superlists-staging.bdienterprises.com.service: Failed with result 'resour
May 09 15:37:12 avidfisherman systemd[1]: Failed to start Gunicorn server for superlists-staging.bdienterprises.com.
~
```

Anyone here is familiar with this issue? Your help would be so appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Please copy paste the text of the error instead of linking an image. People use this site via text search. That's how they find solutions to problems (they google error messages or they type the error messages directly in the stackoverflow search bar). Using images prevents future users from finding this post and a potential solution to their problem.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback - I will edit this as per your suggestion.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional Does this look better? Pls let me know if you are familiar with this issue I am stuck with for a little while.

Comment: Yes it looks good now. I've never encountered this issue.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional Thank you! I finally got it solved by finding a minor mistake I made after many attempts.

Comment: Happy to hear you solved this. If you have the time, maybe you can write your solution here as a reply (you can accept your own reply). Who knows maybe it'll spare some headache to a visitor of the future.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can result from an ambiguity in the book Test-Driven Development with Python (obeythetestinggoat.com).

The error is likely because required packages, or even Gunicorn itself, haven't yet been installed on your server (for example, if you follow the instructions in the appendix of that book on provisioning using Ansible before deploying and installing required packages). To resolve this, reinstall the packages from your requirements.txt or, if you've already created a fab file, re-run your Fabric script.